# Using ctrl+d to end caesar cipher

Tags: c, command-line

I know there are a few similar questions already posted, but all the solutions I tried did not fix my code. So, my caesar cipher is working as intended. However, I want to be able to exit using ctrl+d, rather than ctrl+c. My code right now is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
        char code[500], ch; 
        int c, key;
        key = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("%s",code);
        for(;;){
                fgets(code, 500, stdin);
                for(c = 0;code[c] != '\0'; ++c){
                        ch = code[c];
                        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                                ch = ch + key;
                                if(ch > 'z'){
                                        ch = ch - 26 ;
                                }
                                else if(ch < 'a'){
                                        ch = ch + 26;
                                }
                                code[c] = ch;
                        }
                        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                                ch = ch + key;
                                if(ch > 'Z'){
                                        ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                                }
                                else if(ch < 'A'){
                                        ch = ch + 26;
                                }
                                code[c] = ch;
                        }
                }
                printf("%s\n", code);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, run it, and type

```
./a.out 2
abc
```

it returns "cde" and leaves the command line hanging so I can type another string.
However, when I press ctrl+d, it just reiterates the program (if I press ctrl+d after seeing cde, it will return efg), when I want it to exit the program when I press it.

One solution I found was to add a

```
if(code == EOF (or '\0' or NULL)) {
   break;
}
```

Aside from warning me that there was point and integer comparison warning, none of them worked.
Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tip: Instead of littering your code with "magic numbers" like 500, define a variable or constant to represent that. This avoids slip-ups when you change most but not all of them in a subsequent alteration.

Comment: Fun to read, thanks Cencoroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
 for(;;){
                fgets(code, 500, stdin);
```

with:

```
while (fgets(code, sizeof code, stdin)) {
```

and EOF will cause fgets to return NULL, thus stopping your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your program isn't reading it directly when you type, your operating system reads everything first, and when it sees a Ctrl+C, it sends an interrupt to the program to stop what its doing.  In order to get this to work, you would have to go into the settings of whatever operating system you are running, and set that up as a hotkey.